# Adding upvotes to reactjs and Firebase chatroom

Tags: firebase, reactjs

https://github.com/kristinyim/ClassroomChat

I want to add an upvoting feature to the messages on this chatroom similar to what you have on GroupMe, but I'm new to React and built this off of a tutorial so don't know where to even begin. I'm good with webdev but am just getting started with the basics of React.js and Firebase. Thanks!

Comment: From the code in your repo there is no way to tell the structure of your firebase database. Can you add that to your question please?

Answer (score 0):

*NB:* There are many ways to achieve this, so the following is just a suggestion.

First you must think of how you want to store your data in the database. If you have users, messages and message-likes, you could structure it like this:

```
"root": {
    "users": {
        "$userId": {
            ...
            "messages": {
                "$messageId1": true,
                "$messageId2": true,
                ...
            }
        }
    },
    "messages": {
        "$messageId": {
            "author": $userId,
            "timestamp": ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
        }
    },
    "likesToMessages": {
        "$messageId": {
            "$likeId": {
                liker: $userId,
                "message": $messageId,
                "timestamp": ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever a user clicks "like" on a message, you want to write to

```
var messageId = ?; // The id of the message that was liked
var like = {
    liker: currentUserId, // id of logged in user
    message: messageId,
    timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP      
};
firebase.database.ref().child('likesToMessages').child(messageId).push(like);
```

Then you get a new `like` in the database, matching the proposed structure.

Then, when you want to read and show the count of likes for a message, you can do like this:

```
const Message = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        message: React.PropTypes.object,
        messageId: React.PropTypes.string // you need to add this prop
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        firebase.database.ref().child('likesToMessages').child(this.props.messageId).on('value', this.onLikesUpdated)
    }

    onLikesUpdated(dataSnapshot) {
        var likes = snap.val();
        this.setState({
            likes
        });
    }

    render() {
        const {name, message} = this.props.message;
        const emojifiedString = emoji.emojify(message);

        return (
            <p>
                {name}: {emojifiedString} [{this.state.likes.length}&hearts;]
            </p>
        );
    }
});
```

Also, in your database security rules, you'd want to index by `timestamp` for message and like so you can quickly query the newest messages.

Also, feel free to check out a similar app I made, code in [GitHub](https://github.com/arnemahl/wooperate) and demo on [wooperate.firebaseapp.com](https://wooperate.firebaseapp.com/#/login).